# How to calculate auto-covariance in Python

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I want to calculate auto-covariance of 3 arrays X1, X2 and Y which are all stationary random process. Is there any function in sciPy or other library can solve this problem?

Answer (score 11):

Statsmodels has auto- and cross covariance functions

http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/devel/generated/statsmodels.tsa.stattools.acovf.html
http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/devel/generated/statsmodels.tsa.stattools.ccovf.html

plus the correlation functions and partial autocorrelation
http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/devel/tsa.html#descriptive-statistics-and-tests

Answer (score 8):

According to the standard estimation of the autocovariance coefficient for discrete signals, which can be expressed by equation:

[image]

...where `x(i)` is a given signal (i.e specific 1D vector), `k` stands for the shift of `x(i)` signal by `k` samples, `N` is the length of `x(i)` signal, and:

[image]

...which is simple average, we can write:

```
'''
Calculate the autocovarriance coefficient.
'''

import numpy as np

Xi = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
N = np.size(Xi)
k = 5
Xs = np.average(Xi)

def autocovariance(Xi, N, k, Xs):
    autoCov = 0
    for i in np.arange(0, N-k):
        autoCov += ((Xi[i+k])-Xs)*(Xi[i]-Xs)
    return (1/(N-1))*autoCov

print("Autocovariance:", autocovariance(Xi, N, k, Xs))
```

If you would like to normalize the autocovariance coefficient, which will become the autocorrelation coefficient expressed as:

[image]

...than you just have to add to the above code just two additional lines:

```
def autocorrelation():
    return autocovariance(Xi, N, k, Xs) / autocovariance(Xi, N, 0, Xs)
```

Here is full script:

```
'''
Calculate the autocovarriance and autocorrelation coefficients.
'''

import numpy as np

Xi = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
N = np.size(Xi)
k = 5
Xs = np.average(Xi)

def autocovariance(Xi, N, k, Xs):
    autoCov = 0
    for i in np.arange(0, N-k):
        autoCov += ((Xi[i+k])-Xs)*(Xi[i]-Xs)
    return (1/(N-1))*autoCov

def autocorrelation():
    return autocovariance(Xi, N, k, Xs) / autocovariance(Xi, N, 0, Xs)

print("Autocovariance:", autocovariance(Xi, N, k, Xs))
print("Autocorrelation:", autocorrelation())
```

Comment: Numpy already has everything needed to compute the [correlation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.correlate.html). (Which can even be accelerated with [scipy.signal.fftconvolve](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.15.1/reference/generated/scipy.signal.fftconvolve.html).) Which then only need to be multiplied by the [variance](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.var.html) to get the autocovariance.

Comment: @Celelibi, the problem is to automatically take into account the different number of points for each time lag. It would be much simpler with numpy, if you could replace the `sum` of  `np.correlate` by `avg`.

Answer (score 5):

A small tweak to the previous answers, which avoids python `for` loops and uses numpy array operations instead. This will be quicker if you have a lot of data.

```
def lagged_auto_cov(Xi,t):
    """
    for series of values x_i, length N, compute empirical auto-cov with lag t
    defined: 1/(N-1) * \sum_{i=0}^{N-t} ( x_i - x_s ) * ( x_{i+t} - x_s )
    """
    N = len(Xi)

    # use sample mean estimate from whole series
    Xs = np.mean(Xi)

    # construct copies of series shifted relative to each other, 
    # with mean subtracted from values
    end_padded_series = np.zeros(N+t)
    end_padded_series[:N] = Xi - Xs
    start_padded_series = np.zeros(N+t)
    start_padded_series[t:] = Xi - Xs

    auto_cov = 1./(N-1) * np.sum( start_padded_series*end_padded_series )
    return auto_cov
```

Comparing this against [@bluevoxel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2652811/bluevoxel)'s code, using a time-series of 50,000 data points and computing the auto-correlation for a single fixed value of lag, the python `for` loop code averaged about 30 milli-seconds and using numpy arrays averaged faster than 0.3 milli-seconds (running on my laptop).

Comment: I suggest using np.dot(start_padded_series, end_padded_series) instead of np.sum(start_padded_series*end_padded_series). In addition, I believe the Bessel correction in this case is 1/(N-t), not  1/(N-1).

Answer (score 2):

Get sample auto covariance:

```
# cov_auto_samp(X,delta)/cov_auto_samp(X,0) = auto correlation
def cov_auto_samp(X,delta):
    N = len(X)
    Xs = np.average(X)
    autoCov = 0.0
    times = 0.0
    for i in np.arange(0, N-delta):
        autoCov += (X[i+delta]-Xs)*(X[i]-Xs)
        times +=1
    return autoCov/times
```

Answer (score 1):

[@user333700](https://stackoverflow.com/users/333700/user333700) has the right answer. Using a library (such as [statsmodels](https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/index.html)) is generally preferred over writing your own. However, it is insightful to implement your own at least once.

```
def _check_autocovariance_input(x):
        if len(x) < 2:
            raise ValueError('Need at least two elements to calculate autocovariance')

def get_autocovariance_given_lag(x, lag):
    _check_autocovariance_input(x)

    x_centered = x - np.mean(x)
    a = np.pad(x_centered, pad_width=(0, lag), mode='constant')
    b = np.pad(x_centered, pad_width=(lag, 0), mode='constant')
    return np.dot(a, b) / len(x)

def get_autocovariance(x):
    _check_autocovariance_input(x)
    x_centered = x - np.mean(x)
    return np.correlate(x_centered, x_centered, mode='full')[len(x) - 1:] / len(x)
```

The function I have `get_autocovariance_given_lag` calculates the autocovariance for a given lag.

If you are interested in all lags, the `get_autocovariance` can be used. The `np.correlate` function is what `statsmodels` uses under the hood. It calculates the cross correlation. This is a sliding dot product. For example, suppose the array is [1, 2, 3]. Then we get:

```
      [1, 2, 3]      = 3 * 1 = 3
[1, 2, 3]

      [1, 2, 3]      = 2 * 1 + 3 * 2 = 8
   [1, 2, 3]


      [1, 2, 3]      = 1 * 1 + 2 * 2 + 3 * 3 = 14
      [1, 2, 3]

      [1, 2, 3]      = 2 * 1 + 3 * 2 = 8
         [1, 2, 3]

      [1, 2, 3]      = 3 * 1 = 3
            [1, 2, 3]
```

But note we are interested in the covariance that starts at lag 0. Where is this? Well, this occurs after we have moved `N - 1` positions to the right where `N` is the length of the array. This is why we return the array starting at `N-1`.